# performing an if statement on an multidimensional array without knowing the key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

First of all let me try and explain what I'm trying to do.

I have a calendar with events that are stored in the database, each event is a workday. The important things I save in the database is the user, the date, the week of the year (1-52) and the hours worked. Now I want to calculate the paychecks by adding up the hours worked by grouping the hours worked in week 1, 2, 3, …, 51, and 52. The code I have so far is:

```
<?php
include ('require.php');
include ('dblink.php');
$time =[];
$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM events WHERE user = '".$_SESSION['s_username']."'") or die(mysqli_error());
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
           if($row['week'] % 2 == 0){
            $week = $row['week'] - 1; // if its an even week then -1 to make it an odd week to add up the hours of the two weeks together.
        }else{
            $week = $row['week'];
        }
        if (isset($time['week']) && $time['week'] == $week){
            $time['hours'] += $row['hours']; //If the previous week was added then add the second week to it.
        }else{
            $year = explode("-", $row['date']);
            $time[] = array('week' => $week, 'hours' => $row['hours'], 'year' => $year[0]);
        }
    }
}
foreach($time as $indTime){
    echo $indTime['hours'].' hours were spent on the '.$indTime['week'].' week of '.$indTime['year'] . '<br />'; 
}
?>
```

The problem arises at line 13 where I have an `if` statement. I know it's incorrect because my array is multidimensional and `$time['week']` isn't defined. But I don't know the key so I can't do, say, `$time[23]['week']`.

To try and further explain what I mean let me show an example of my output.

```
4.75 hours were spent on the 41 week of 2013
7.5 hours were spent on the 41 week of 2013
4 hours were spent on the 43 week of 2013
7.5 hours were spent on the 43 week of 2013
7.5 hours were spent on the 43 week of 2013
4.5 hours were spent on the 43 week of 2013
6 hours were spent on the 43 week of 2013
4 hours were spent on the 43 week of 2013
7.5 hours were spent on the 43 week of 2013
7 hours were spent on the 45 week of 2013
8 hours were spent on the 45 week of 2013
8 hours were spent on the 45 week of 2013
4.5 hours were spent on the 45 week of 2013
6 hours were spent on the 45 week of 2013
7.5 hours were spent on the 45 week of 2013
5.5 hours were spent on the 45 week of 2013
8 hours were spent on the 45 week of 2013
```

Since my `if` statement doesn't work, it just creates a new array for every row in my database. But in reality what I want it to do is add up the hours for each week that is that same. So all the week 41 would be added together and hours would be 12.25, for example. Anyone know what I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using automatically incremented array keys, use week numbers as the keys:

```
else{
    $year = explode("-", $row['date']);
    $time[$week] = array('week' => $week,'hours' => $row['hours'],'year' => $year[0]);
}
```

Aside: probably it would be more accurate to write `$year = explode("-", $row['date'], 2)[0]` (PHP >= 5.4) and use `$year` directly, or perhaps even `$year = (int)$row['date']` since the format seems to be assumed anyway.

This allows you to "know" what key to use to index into the multidimensional array in order to consolidate hours worked:

```
if (isset($time[$week])){
    $time[$week]['hours'] += $row['hours'];
}
```

This would solve the problem in PHP. However, it would be better if possible to express the operation in SQL instead and let the database do the grouping and sum of the hours.

Comment: how would I use the week number as the key? Im pretty new to this.

Comment: @user2989367: First code snippet, `$time[$week] = ...`. But you should really look into writing it directly as SQL.

Comment: oh sorry didnt see the change.

Answer (score 2):

From what you have said so far (Correct me if I am wrong), it would appear that you need to `group` all hours from within a `week`, from specific `users`?

If this is correct, adding a `GROUP BY` clause on the WEEK field, should yield results that should give you what you want.

I just wrote an sqlFiddle, so you can see what I mean: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f49a3/2

If that is the desired end result, by adding a `user` to the SQL, you will be able to just group AND order by the week, giving you a run down of hours.

If I am wrong, let me know with an explanation, and I'll try again :)

---

EDIT:

If the above is right, then by changing the SQL, you should be able to cut the code down to something similar to;

```
<?php
include ('require.php');
include ('dblink.php');

$sql     = "SELECT `week`, `year` SUM(`hours`) AS `weekly_hours` FROM `events` WHERE `user` = '".$_SESSION['s_username']."' GROUP BY `week` ORDER BY `week` DESC";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
    {
        echo number_format($row['weekly_hours'], 2) . ' hours were spent on the ' . $row['week'] . ' week of ' . $row['year'] . '<br />'; 
    }
}
?>
```